# Concave or Convex of some functions?

Tags: analysis

I would like to know whether these two functions are concave or convex:

1.the first is $$ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto (x-1)^3$$

Here I would say that the function is  ist concave for $x \leq 0$ and convex for $x \geq 0$

1. the second one is $e^{-x^2}$ and here I would say its concave...

Am I right?

Thx

Comment: Are you just blindly guessing?

Comment: no, i draw a plot

Comment: Then you didn't drew it correctly...or else you don't know what's concave and what's convex. Can you do second derivatives?

Comment: yes i think I can $6(x-1)$

Comment: Do you know the definitions of concave and convex? Why do you think $(x-1)^3$ is convex for $x\in(0,1)$?

Comment: Could someone just explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the basic theorem: if a function $\;f\;$ is twice differentiable in an interval $\;[a,b]\;$ , then it is upwards concave (convex) in that interval iff $\;f''(x)>0\;\;\forall\,x\in [a,b]\;$ .

In our case

$$f(x)=(x-1)^3\implies f''(x)=6(x-1)>0\iff x>1\;\ldots$$

Comment: So its just upwards concave for $x>1$ ? THX

Comment: Yup, @Mamba...and downwards concave elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Put $f(x) = e^{-x^2}.$ Then you have
$$f'(x) = -2xe^{-x^2}$$
and 
$$f''(x) = -2(1 - 2x^2)e^{-x^2}$$
The second derivative is negative for $|x| < 1/\sqrt{2}$ and it is positive
otherwise.  Therein lies the tale of this function's convexity.